# Java: Do all mutable variables need to be volatile when using locks?

Tags: java, locking, concurrency, volatile, synchronized

Does the following variable, x, need to be volatile?

Or does the manipulation within a utils.concurrent lock perform the same function as a synchronized block (ensuring it's written to memory, and not stored in cpu cache)?

```
myMethod(){
  myLock.lock();
  x++;
  myLock.unlock();
}
```

Comment: In real code, you unlock in `finally` clause, don't you?

Comment: Great point Alexander, yes, I just realized that was a problem of mine and had to fix some code to put the unlock in finally blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such variables only need to be volatile if they're accessed elsewhere without a lock.  For example, as a fast read-only access to a size variable.  The lock methods do serve the same purpose as a synchronized block.  See the "Memory Synchronization" section in the javadoc for the [Lock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) class.